# Skipping Read URL data of IP Camera in MS Access Which is not Active C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, camera, emgucv

I have a problem. I have a database that contains URLs of IP Cameras. My program will read all of the URLs from that database. But additionally, I would like to exclude all URLs of cameras that are inactive. If my program connects to URL of inactive camera, it hangs. I use Emgu CV to do image processing. These are what I have done.

```
string koneksi = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=D:\Dokumen\Alfon\TA Alfon\CobaFitur\SistemParkir.accdb; 
                                     Persist Security Info=False";

private void ProsesSemuaKamera()
{
  OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
  OleDbCommand commandurl = kon.CreateCommand();
  kon.Open();
  string selectsemuaurl = "select * from datakamera";
  commandurl.CommandText = selectsemuaurl;
  OleDbDataReader prosessemuaurl = commandurl.ExecuteReader();

  while (prosessemuaurl.Read())
  {
    CaptureSemuaKamera = new Capture(prosessemuaurl["urlkamera"].ToString()); //(352x288)
    Application.Idle += ProcessFrameSemuaKamera;
    ProsesCapture = !ProsesCapture;
  }
  kon.Close();
}
```

Comment: You should have a timeout on URL connection so that your program doesn't hang, but loads for 5 seconds than gives up and skips to next camera.

Comment: @TomášZato - Thanks for your answer. Can you help me to do that ? I am newbie for this :(

Comment: I don't know, I never used that library or URL IO in C#. But the `new Capture` must provide working timeout somehow. Read the documentation, I don't know anything about it, I just know how these things usually work.

Comment: @TomášZato -  Thanks for your advice. It gives me a direction what I must do. Thanks :)